# Django wagtail, error uploading a video to a text block

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wagtail

When I try to upload a video through the built-in textbox functionality, I get an error:

> Request Method:   POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/178/edit/
>   Django Version: 1.11
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'function' object has no attribute 'void_element_close_prefix'

At the same time, I already have a page with such a video, and when I try to re-publish it gets the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have version 4.6.1 of the `beautifulsoup4` library installed. This version has a critical bug which breaks Wagtail - you should downgrade to 4.6.0.